# When adding a filter, the photo is stretched

Tags: ios, swift, imageview, ciimage

When adding a filter, the photo is stretched and does not respond to the aspectFit

```
    let photoProcess = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectProcess")

    let image = UIImage(named: "tetka")

    let ciImage = CIImage(image: image!)

    let test = photoProcess?.outputImage

    let img = UIImage(ciImage: test!)

    photoImageView.image = img
    photoImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this code

```
    let inputImage = UIImage(named: "blueDog.png")!
    let ciContext = CIContext(options: nil)
    let coreImage = CIImage(image: inputImage)
    let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectProcess" )
    filter!.setDefaults()
    filter!.setValue(coreImage, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
    let filteredImageData = filter!.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
    let filteredImageRef = ciContext.createCGImage(filteredImageData, from: filteredImageData.extent)
    let imageForUser = UIImage(cgImage: filteredImageRef!);

    photoImgVw.image = imageForUser
```

You may get more info from this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-sdk-apply-photo-filters-with-core-image-in-swift--cms-27142)

**Output**

[image]

Comment: kindly accept this answer also. It will be useful for SO followers too..